# SQL: converting rows into columns

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I currently have a table that looks like the following:

| user_id | device_id | device_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12_aa | 1245 | mobile |
| 15_ab | 8909 | tablet |
| 17-ya | 9090 | mobile |
| 18-ac | 8900 | desktop |

I am trying to convert this table to below:

| user_id | mobile | tablet | desktop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12_aa | 1245 | null | null |
| 15_ab | null | 8909 | null |
| 17_ya | 9090 | null | null |
| 18_ac | null | null | 8900 |

Could you help how this can be achieved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id,
       max(case when device_type = 'mobile' then device_id end) as mobile,
       max(case when device_type = 'tablet' then device_id end) as tablet,
       max(case when device_type = 'desktop' then device_id end) as desktop
from t
group by user_id;
```

Comment: That was very quick! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use below

```
select * from `project.dataset.table`
pivot (max(device_id) for device_type in ('mobile', 'tablet', 'desktop'))
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]